# SOLVED Switching user in automated scripts like cron jobs

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, users, su

If I run `su -c "notify-send test" myusername` as root, the command will be executed by myusername (me).

But if I place a script in /etc/cron.daily or /lib/systemd/system-sleep and it is automatically run by root, this command will not executed by me (e.g. for notify-send, there will not be a notification on my desktop but this problem is not specific to notify-send).

Why are the behaviors different if technically, the same user (root) should be running the same script and the same user (I) should be running the same notify command?

I hope you can help me. I'll be happy to provide further information or clarification if it's hard to understand what I mean.

Comment: Can you verify the script is run at all when put in cron.daily?

Comment: yes, all other commands in the script do run

Comment: For cron, looks like a classic case of missing environment variables. Cronjobs do not run in your environment; they run in cron's limited environment with permission to impersonate you when reading/writing files. So all your environment variables (see them using `printenv`) are missing - cron doesn't know about your login sessions, and doesn't care. Usual advice for cron is either to log all output, or look up how to export environment variables to the cronjob.

Comment: Thank you, exporting all variables from the output of `printenv` did the job :)